# File Compression Statistics

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, descriptive-statistics, sufficient-statistics

**Statically**, how is the compression of a file possible? As in, a file n bytes long can have $2^{n*8}$ (the 'times 8' part is because there are 8 bits in a byte). So, if you decrease the size then statistically it shouldn't **not** possible to decrease a file's size (compress it) and be able to perfectly reassemble the original file because the total number of different possibilities for the input will be greater than the output, so u cant exactly get the input from the output.

So, what is going on (in statistical terms)!?!?!?!

Please note that I am not trying to disprove compression (I ♥<sup>∞</sup> compression (because I am a programmer)), I just want to know the statistics behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have essentially rediscovered the theorem that says that any faithful compression algorithm must increase the size of some input files in order to compress others - one hopes, most others.

Google

> lossless compression pigeonhole principle

for several links.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle#Uses_and_applications

http://matt.might.net/articles/why-infinite-or-guaranteed-file-compression-is-impossible/

...

Comment: Not "most others", but "most files you want to compress"

Comment: @Henry Fair comment thanks.

Comment: cool! thxs for the links

Comment: btw, extreme example of reverse compression (I made this file by accident, but that's not the point - the point is that it exists): https://www.dropbox.com/s/sf6r0q9f5m4mf7p/DOS%20programs.7z?dl=0